# jss how to change opacity for a color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

Currently I am using the following code to add a color to an element using jss.

```js
const styleSheet = theme => ({
  root: {
     backgroundColor: theme.colors.red,
  },
})
```

I would like to know if exist a function to add opacity based on color`theme.colors.red`.

example smt like: 
`backgroundColor: color(theme.colors.red, .05),`

Comment: from what I can tell from the documentation can you not just set the `opacity` property? https://github.com/cssinjs/cssinjs/search?utf8=&q=opacity&type=

Comment: opacity is for all the element I need instead just change the value inside the background color

Comment: Assuming I understand the question correctly, you should remove the `jss` tag

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Material UI has a `colorManipulator` [utility file](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/colorManipulator.js#L231-L249), which includes an `alpha` function:

```js
import { alpha } from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';

/**
 * Sets the absolute transparency of a color.
 * Any existing alpha values are overwritten.
 * @param {string} color - CSS color, i.e. one of: #nnn, #nnnnnn, rgb(), rgba(), hsl(), hsla(), color()
 * @param {number} value - value to set the alpha channel to in the range 0 - 1
 * @returns {string} A CSS color string. Hex input values are returned as rgb
 */

{
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.colors.red, 0.5)
}
```

For Mui v5:

```
import { alpha } from "@mui/material";
```

---

Alternatively, you can add the [color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color) library from npm for color manipulation:

```js
import Color from 'color';

{
    backgroundColor: Color(theme.colors.red).alpha(0.5).string()
}
```

Comment: The solution in this answer is now deprecated in the latest Material-UI. Use `alpha` instead of `fade`

Comment: For **Mui v5**, you need to add this code: `import { alpha } from "@mui/material";`

Comment: for Mui v4: `import { alpha } from '@material-ui/core'`

Comment: for Mui v5: `import { alpha } from '@mui/material/styles'`. See: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#styles

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can use the fade function provided in Material UI Next.

```
import {fade} from 'material-ui/styles/colorManipulator';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        boxShadow: `0 4px 8px 0 ${fade(defaultTheme.palette.primary[500], 0.18)}`,
      }
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Here's how it's working : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/styles/colorManipulator.js#L157-L164

Another solution could be to use similar color functions from https://github.com/styled-components/polished

Comment: in version 4 of material-ui that is now: 

````import {fade} from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';````

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you don't already have the alpha channel defined in the color, you can also do:

```
backgroundColor: theme.colors.red + '00'
```

This will set alpha channel to 0, thus transparent. You can append any value between `'00'` to `'ff'`

Comment: This is the fastest and most straight-forward solution. Can't believe this was so hard to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

for MUI v5 this seems to work:

```
import { alpha } from '@mui/material';
```

...

```
MuiContainer: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '&.MuiContainer-asideWithImage': {
            backgroundColor: alpha(MY_COLOR, 0.78),
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

...

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution using

```
 backgroundColor: theme.utils.rgba(theme.axColor.black, 0.7),
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me with the latest version of Material-UI. I can't find it in the documentation either. Do you have a link?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in the current version. @Romainpetit solution works.

Answer (score 4):

Some of these answers are referencing deprecated Material-UI functions. The current preferred approach is to use `alpha`:

```
import { alpha } from "@material-ui/core";

...
                 // yields rgba(255,255,255,0.85)
backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.background.paper, 0.85)
```

Comment: can't find any reference in the official documentation, and is not available in the current v4 version

Answer (score 2):

You can use RGBA values

```
const styleSheet = theme => ({
  root: {
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
  },
})
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors.html

Comment: sorry I wanted to re-use value for my variable

Comment: Make theme.colors.red an rgba value

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is:

```
import color from "color"

const themeColorsRed = color
  .rgb(theme.colors.red)
  .array()
```

Then you can do:

```
{
  backgroundColor: `rgba(${themeColorsRed}, 0.05)`,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, an 8 digit hex code works too

```
const styleSheet = theme => ({
  root: {
     backgroundColor: '#ffffff80',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current v5 of mui use this from the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#provide-tokens-manually):

```
import { useTheme,alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';

...

const theme = useTheme();

...

backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.background.default,0.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the MUI5 you can use `theme` locally:

```
import {alpha} from '@mui/material';

const styles = {
   background: (theme) => alpha(theme.palette.colors.yousColorName, 0.1),
}
```